# django custom forms with models, also with 'choices' as values, how should I approach this problem?

Tags: django, django-forms

django forms is giving me a pretty bad headache...

I've been struggling with this for 2 hours now.

I wanted to make a custom form for a model to be able to add objects to it and also be able to move the fields as I want to (instead of using form.as_p (or form|crispy), I wanted to put the entire form in a grid-like table using a custom pattern, not only putting one under another) but whenever I put a choicefield (which is either a choicefield or a foreignkey) their values are empty and also, 3 out of 4 formfields are actually shown, one remains the default.

It contains `fields='__all__'` with 3 choicefields and 1 floatfield each with a label, nothing more.

To show the forms in html I used

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {{ field.label_tag }}

                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field }}
                {{ field.help_text }}

        {% endfor %}
```

which works well. Am I trying to solve the problem in a wrong way? I'll come back to this topic tomorrow, I'll need some rest now but I don't understand why passing a `choices=TheModel # or # choices=TheModel.ojbects.all()` breaks the entire thing.

**Is there a website or a youtube channel that shows some solutions to those problems?**

I lokoed up a bunch of sites and videos but they never access foreign keys as values to forms(dropdowns), never make grouped dropdowns (which I made and is working without custom forms).

Small update, I'm trying with 'labels' and '|as_crispy_field' tags but "exptype" is not changing. Everything else does. and its name is matched too.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaiEd.jpg

( multiple screenshots attached )

Answer (score 0):

Choices needs to be a tuple like this:

```
[
    ('CHOICE_ONE', 'choice_one')
]
```

So, you could create the choices list like this (Lets assume `TheModel` has a `name` field.)

```
choices = [(i.id, i.name) for i in TheModel.objects.all()]
```

The second value will be displayed to the user, the first one will be set in the database.

You could use a ModelChoiceField:

```
class FooMultipleChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    foo_select = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foo_select'].queryset = ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield